# Concurrent processing with spring inbound file adapter

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, spring-integration

I have a file system directory that I want to poll for files and then process each file concurrently, with a single thread per file. My impression was that, under the cover, `InboundFileAdapter` puts each file into a queue, so I could then use an executor channel downstream to have later calls be processed concurrently. I implemented that in Java Config as follows:

```
return IntegrationFlows
            .from(s -> s.file(inboundMessageDirectory.toFile(), Comparator.comparing(File::lastModified)) // serve oldest first
                            .scanner(directoryScanner) // we know the directory structure, so we can take advantage of that with a custom scanner
                            .filter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>(MAX_FILTER_CAPACITY)), // limit number of references in memory
                    e -> e.poller(Pollers
                            .fixedDelay(fileSystemPollDelay)
                            .get()))
            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(executor).get())
            .transform(File::toPath)
            .enrichHeaders(cleanUpConfigurer)
            .get()
```

Every channel downstream of the executor channel is itself a direct channel.

However, I see see poor concurrency in the downstream services. With a cached thread pool, I see the same thread executing the downstream code essentially serially, while if I use a fixed pool executor, I see different threads trading off for still serial execution.

I've also tried putting a bridge between the poller and the executor channel, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just because of `SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean` under hood:

```
if (this.pollerMetadata.getMaxMessagesPerPoll() == Integer.MIN_VALUE){
    // the default is 1 since a source might return
    // a non-null and non-interruptible value every time it is invoked
    this.pollerMetadata.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(1);
}
```

So, each your `.fixedDelay(fileSystemPollDelay)` only one `File` is polled from the queue to process.

So, just increase `.maxMessagesPerPoll()` to some appropriate for your system value and have fun with the concurrency!

BTW, there is no reason to introduce `ExecutorChannel` just after the polling adapter. You simply can use `.taskExecutor()` for the `.poller()` exactly for the same concurrency reason.